# Are supergroups available on Telegram app for ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, telegram

Is this in work? My group turned into a supergroup and now it doesnt work with ubuntu touch yet. there are no updates yet. What else can I say.

Comment: You may follow this bug: http://pad.lv/1565949 for updates. Also I'm not used to groups/supergroups, but do clients based on Telegram 's web version (example: https://uappexplorer.com/app/webtelegram.markcortbass) work?

Comment: UBports is currently working on making Supergroups available: https://forums.ubports.com/topic/183/telegram-app-improvements